# Tensorflow :DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. /Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow

My scripts were running perfectly before, but know I am facing this error of tensorflow.
I have tried reinstalling it, but no use...
Someone please try to help me in figuring it out.

Here the error look like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\AMR\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\AMR\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tensorflow2\models\research\object_detection\Object_detection_image.py", line 15, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\AMR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\AMR\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\AMR\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```